# Accessing Django model fields throws NameError inside of dictionary

Tags: python, django, dictionary, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to return a dictionary via DRF's Response(), but I can't access any model fields from within the dictionary.

I tried returning a single field's value without first packing the data into a dictionary, and it worked. I know that Django's querysets are lazy and only hit the DB on evaluation, but I'm stumped by why my model suddenly has no fields when it's accessed inside of a dictionary.

```py
@api_view(['GET'])
def arDetail(request):
    '''
    gets data from model and puts it into a dict to be returned
    '''
    model = model.objects.get(pk=int(request.GET["pk"]))
    #return Response(model.pk) WORKS here, but throws a nameerror
    #when accessed in rspData
    rspData = {
        pk: model.pk,
        problem: model.problem,
        solution: model.solution,
        primaryCategory: model.primaryCategory,
        secondaryCategory: model.secondaryCategory,
        profilePic: model.author.profilePic
    }
    return Response(rspData)
```

I need to pull URLS and whatnot from other models, so I can't just use DRF's serializers as I do on my other models. What should happen is that I set each of the necessary fields in the dictionary and then return that with Response(), but I can't access model fields from within the rspData dictionary. Instead, Django throws a NameError on the first line of the dict, (and any others if I comment out fields to look for offenders).

Comment: Show the actual error with the full traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
    rspData = {
        "pk": model.pk,
        "problem": model.problem,
        "solution": model.solution,
        "primaryCategory": model.primaryCategory,
        "secondaryCategory": model.secondaryCategory,
        "profilePic": model.author.profilePic
    }
```

Your dict is missing quotes

Comment: That was all it was! I blame JS ;)

Comment: i spotted the js by the type of your variable :)
rsp_data != rspData